# How to stop jQuery SlidesJS slideshow?

Tags: jquery, slidesjs

I'm using the SlidesJS slideshow plugin. It works great but I need to stop the slideshow programmatically. The plugin can generate a stop and play button but I need to have the ability to start and stop the slideshow without the user clicking these buttons.

The slidehow is created like this:

```
$('#slides').slidesjs();
```

I'm using Version 3 of the plugin and I can't find anything in the docs.

I did find this solution (http://seankstewart.com/lab/js/jquery/plugins/Slides/examples/images-with-captions/index-test.html#) but it's for version 1 of the plugin.

Thanks for any help,

Andrew.

Answer (score 0):

You can use option:

```
play: {
  auto: true,
}
```

Then you may hide controls with css:

```
.slidesjs-pagination {
    display: none;
}
```

And finaly use click event for start/stop slider:

```
$('.slidesjs-stop').click();
$('.slidesjs-play').click();
```